# Using Linq .net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq

I am trying to do something simple, but somehow I can't get it to work. I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and want to use Linq in a .net 4.5 webform application.

I currently use these assemblies:

```
<!-- ASP.NET 4.0 Assemblies -->
<add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
<add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

I do know there is a version 4.0.0.0 in it. but I can't change it to 4.5 since 4.5 does not have a System.xml.linq because it's deprecated. Also I keep getting `asenumerable' is not a member of 'system.data.datatable'.` and I know I need the reference to system.data.datasetextensions, but it keeps giving the error when I have the above assemblies.

How can I add Linq to my .net 4.5 webform application? I've searched the internet but did not found any solutions.

Comment: I think you just want System.Linq, not System.Xml.Linq, which you should be able to do without actually adding the assemblies in your web.config.  Just do using System.Linq.

Comment: The error I get on importing the system.linq on top of my file: `namespace or type specified in the imports system.linq`

Answer (score 1):

The System.Linq namespace is in the System.Core assembly (in System.Core.dll).
You don't need an import.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you give an example on how to import it in the web.config? Cu's I currently have 4.0.0 in the Web.config. How should my web.config look? Thank you. When I do add reference to the project, the system.core is not there.

Comment: No changes to web.config are necessary. By default, "using System.Linq;" is at the top of my Default.cs (new 4.5 web application in VS 2013) That is all I needed. Capitalization counts. What version of VS are you using?